# Debugging rails web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, netbeans-6.9

I have an android app as client and a **rails REST webservice**.Rails application is running on the local host.I have installed the fast debugger on Netbeans.I am using WEBrick server right now.

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.1 version and my netbeans IDE is 6.9 .

When i run my application I have found that the application is deployed properly on to the server and the output is shown on the console but when i debug my application nothing happens and no output is shown on the console and when i try to hit localhost:3000 from the browser it displays '**could not connect to the web server cannot show http://localhost:3000**'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when i changed the ruby platform from 1.9.2 to 1.8.7-p174.

P.S. :Sometimes the gem paths set by netbeans would be wrong.Please check it and correct it if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your debugger to the Rails application, and set a breakpoint on the method that gets called when your client connects?

Comment: Do i have to change any other settings for this?Currently the fast debugger is not working for me on NetBeans.